# Curl PHP API Post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am wanting to post to an API in woocommerce php file i used code below.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.feverfinance.co.za/FTIntegration.svc/BalanceLookup");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode( $username .":" .$password ) ,
            'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' ,

            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check if any error occurred
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {

       print_r($ch);
       print_r($result);
    }

    $obj = json_decode($result,true);
    //Mage::log($result,true);

    $tranactionSuccess =  $obj['Success'];
    $transactionMessage = $obj['Message'];

    curl_close($ch);
```

when i print to console i get ErrorResource id #6.
Please can anyone advise me how to post to API in woocommerce. with the above information that is needed to post to the API

Regards

Comment: First of all, why are you using a CORS proxy for a server-side request? (Which because it is server-side, has nothing whatsoever to do with CORS in the first place.)

Comment: Because its from a http:localhost and the API requests https. if i remove it i get this error in the console when using print_r.WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => User has blocked requests through HTTP.
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: _“Because its from a http:localhost and the API requests https”_ - you are not making much sense here. The request is made from the server side, so CORS doesn’t come into play here at all. And the API URL you are making the request to is an HTTPS one already. And whether you are making the request _from_ a system that itself was accessed via HTTPS or not, is something this API can not even determine on its own.

Comment: The CORS url is used just to bypass the API to receive information from because this is a development setup the URL being sent from would technically be HTTP. this url link was used in magento and worked hence why we thought it could be used in wordpress irrespective of what the API expects. But thank you for your opinion appreciate it

Comment: _“User has blocked requests through HTTP”_ - that does not sound like it is coming from the API in the first place; this is a WP error message. It occurs when you got some sort of SSL library configuration problems on your end. You should investigate and fix _that_ issue, instead of trying to work around it using tools that where not meant for that purpose to begin with.

Comment: alrty k cool, Thanx

Answer (score 0):

First you need to activate woocommerce APIs from wordpress backend and generate API keys

Check https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Then use the following code based on your needs

Example: You need to retrieve product details

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/794");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "consumer_key" . ":" . "consumer_secret");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Note: consumer_key and consumer_secret was generated by API from backend
      and 794 mean product ID

API docs for woocommerce http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/